# in the type InnerList is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

Tags: java, linked-list

I keeping running into this problem with my setInner method where if I keep it as telling me that "The method setInner(GList) in the type InnerList is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)". Which seems odd to me because it seems like an Integer would be applicable to a GList. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

My Inner Class where a list of integers 'inner' will be stored.

```
public class InnerList {
private String name;
private GList<Integer> inner = new GList<Integer>();
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public GList<Integer> getInner() {
    return inner;
}
public void setInner(GList<Integer> inner) {
    this.inner = inner;
}
}
```

The portion of my public class that is causing me problems, within my main method:

```
GList<InnerList> list = new GList<InnerList>(); 
    InnerList iList = new InnerList ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter a number (y/n)?");
            answer = sc.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
                answer = sc.nextLine();
                try {
                    Integer num1 = Integer.valueOf(answer);                            
                    if (list.isEmpty() == true) {                           
                        iList.setInner(num1);  //ERROR IS HERE
                        list.insertFirstItem(iList);
                    } else {
                        iList = new InnerList();
                        iList.setInner(num1); //AND HERE
                        list.insertNext(iList);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("You must enter an number! " + e);
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                break first;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You haven't understood types yet. An Integer is not a GList. It  would be a GList if it extended the class GList. And it doesn't. Even conceptually, I don't see how anyone can imagine that an integer number is a list.

Comment: Not sure what you want to be doing, but your `setInner` method wants a  *list of Integer objects, and you are passing it an Integer.

Comment: so essentially I need another list GList<Integer> nList = new GList<Integer>(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a pretty clear. You are using

```
iList.setInner(num1);
```

when you should be doing

```
iList.setInner(myIntegerGlist);
```

to match the expected argument type of the method.

Comment: list is where the values should be stored; but I made the change for SNG's and the error is the same.

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new `GList<Integer>`. Don't see one in the code above.

Comment: I've had it in off and on; while I trouble shoot the other problems I'm having. Didn't realize it was the cause of this one. Thanks

Comment: I would extract the `GList<Integer>()` a separate variable. I assume you will want to populate it with values...

Comment: It's impossible to say if it does what you expect, because you didn't say it in your question, and didn't write any documentation for your classes and methods.

Comment: So if I'm populating    GList<Integer>(); am I not worried about sending those values to 'list'?

Comment: JB Nizet, if you don't have anything valuable to add please stop commenting on my posts (I don't need a stackoverflow stalker). Even if I had created documentation, you would not see it because I would not post here for you to see. @Reimeus thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChristopherDay: StackOverflow is all about good questions, answers and comments. Whether you like it or not. I just try to help you get an answer. Telling if code will work without knowing what it should do is impossible. If you can't understand that, well, I'm sorry for you. That said, plonk.